# Unable to use bar function after updating to Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab-figure

This is a pretty straight-forward question. I am simply unable to plot a bar graph since I updated to Matlab 2014b.

When I try this simple example from the Matlab documentation :

```
y = [75 91 105 123.5 131 150 179 203 226 249 281.5];
bar(y)
```

I receive the following message (and no figure) :

> Warning: Error updating Bar. Following is the chain of causes of the
>       error:
>
> Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

I run Matlab in UNIX and this was not a problem with Matlab 2013b. I am still able to plot regular lines and even surfaces.

Anyone has the same issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Update** : I restarted Matlab and was able to produce the graph. Then I ran a script that produces a few graphs, and the error occurred again. Maybe there is some variable I need to clear before calling `bar` ?

Comment: **Update** : Same problem with Matlab 2015a, but on Windows 7 now. Still not able to produce a 'bar' graph, same error message.